# Executing a Cygwin process from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, process, cygwin

I'm trying to launch Cygwin version of ruby.exe from a .NET application, but I'm stuck.

```
c:\>"c:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe" c:\test\ruby.rb
/usr/bin/ruby: no such file to load -- ubygems (LoadError)
```

As you see Ruby can't locate libraries because it's looking some Linux style paths.

Obviously when I run ruby.exe from .NET since it can't find libraries it fails like above.

If I don't load any library it works fine :

```
c:\>"c:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe" -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i386-cygwin]
```

Originally cygwin starts with this cygwin.bat

```
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
bash --login -i
```

How can I make .NET to first go into cygwin enviroment and then execute ruby in that enviroment ?

- I can't use Windows Ruby, I need to cygwin ruby.
- I'm aware of potential usage of interactively driving "bash" but that sounds dirty, unless there is nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using perhaps mixing native Windows rubygems and Cygwin ruby? Using Cygwin rubygems seems to work fine for me. (Why is your Cygwin ruby interpreter apparently searching a path with Windows backslashes in it?).

Alternatively, have you tried `run.exe`?

```
C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe -p /starting/dir exe_to_run
```

Here's the man-page entry:

> NAME
>
> run - start programs with hidden console window
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> run [ -p path ] command [ -wait ] arguments
>
> runcommand [ -p path ] [ -wait ] arguments
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Windows  programs  are  either  GUI  programs or console programs. When
>     started console  programs  will  either  attach  to an existing console
>     or  create a new one. GUI programs can  never attach to an exiting con-
>     sole. There is no way to attach to an existing console but hide  it  if
>     started as GUI program.
>
> run  will  do this for you. It works  as intermediate and starts a pro-
>     gram but makes the console window hidden.
>
> With -p path you can add path to the PATH environment variable.
>
> Issuing -wait as first program  argument will make run wait for program
>     completition, otherwise it returns immediately.
>
> The  second  variant  is  for   creating wrappers. If the executable is
>     named runcommand (eg runemacs), run will try  to start the program  (eg
>     emacs).
>
> EXAMPLES
>
> run -p /usr/X11R6/bin xterm
>
> run emacs -wait
>     runemacs -wait
>
> run make -wait

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you execute a non-interactive bash shell which runs ruby from your .NET application? Something like:

```
bash --login -c <your-path-to-ruby> <your-library-to-load>
```

Not sure your file structure, but for example,

```
bash --login -c /usr/bin/ruby ~/test/ruby.rb
```

Look at the [-c option from the bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more info.

Comment: tried this one exactly same problem. giving this error : rb
/usr/bin/ruby: no such file to load -- ubygems (LoadError)

Comment: And if you type the exact same command (the stuff after the -c) from an interactive bash shell you get...?

Comment: actually weird enough unless I start cygwin from cygwin shell it won't work even if I do "bash --login -i"

Comment: I guess cygwin's bash isn't smart enough to understand the file system without cygwin shell...