# How do you run a cygwin-compiled program from windows c# (visual studio)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cygwin

HI,

I would like to run a cygwin compiled program in visual studio using c#

Thanks :)

L

BTW:

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process MyProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\cygwin\\Cygwin.bat";
            MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            MyProcess.Start();
```

This is the code I've tried so far, I have no idea how to make it run the cygwin compiled program tho (AGFL's EP4IR is the targeted program to run)

Thanks

Comment: The same way you would any other program. A cygwin .exe is just a .exe, albeit one with (probably) a dependency on the cygwin DLL.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens after MyProcess.Start() is called?

Comment: no errors, i just dont know how to make it call the agfl from it now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other program. Are you running any concrete well-known program or your own?

Also, see this related question here on StackOverflow: [Executing a Cygwin process from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595600/executing-a-cygwin-process-from-net)

Comment: Ok, are you getting any errors when invoking it just like any other program?

Comment: So far I've just run the cygwin, I don't know how to call the program from the cygwin screen. I'll insert code in my question

Comment: Do not run the `cygwin`. Run the program you want! I.e. do not run `cygwin.exe someprogram.exe` instead run `someprogram.exe`. Then, please post any errors you encounter

Comment: What happend when you change the `FileName` in your sample code to the executable you want to run?